# Java (Eclim + Vim) "system.out.print" not working

Tags: java, vim, println, eclim

I am new to Java programming, and today while messing with eclim and vim, I discovered that the System.out.println(); function is not working.

```
class apples{
public static void main(String args[]){
    double tuna = 5.28;
    System.out.print(tuna);
}
}
```

This does not give me a result.

But when I do:

```
class apples{
public static void main(String args[]){
    double tuna = 5.28;
    System.out.println(tuna);
}
}
```

(The only difference is the "println")
I get 5.28, the correct behavior.

Anyone know why this would happen, or is this the way it should be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.println()` automatically appends a newline, `.print()` does not.

`System.out` is a buffered stream; you need to `.flush()` for the result of `.print()` to appear (do it *after* you print, obviously). The newline in `.println()` causes the output to be flushed, which is why you don't need it there.