# Java System.out.print();, behaves different on Eclipse than on Eclim

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, println, eclim

Im trying to learn some Java, I am using Eclim and after following a tutorial I found that this does not work on Eclim + vim:

```
class variables{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double number;
        number = 12.34;
        System.out.print(number);
    }
}
```

But when I do the same on Eclipse, it does work.
The only way I can make it work on Eclim is by using

```
println
```

instead of

```
print
```

Any ideas on why this would happen??

edit:

Tried this:

```
class variables{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    double number;
    number = 12.34;
    System.out.flush();
    System.out.print(number);
  }
}
```

and still nothing.
Again, it works on Eclipse, but not on Eclim

Comment: I have [already answered that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140928/java-eclim-vim-system-out-print-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use .flush() after .print()
because system.out is buffered stream... you'll have to flush the output before you use it.

In .println(), the output gets flushed automatically

Comment: I tried this and still no go:    class variables{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double number;
        number = 12.34;
        System.out.flush();
        System.out.print(number);
    }
}

Comment: can u pls show the code which you tried

Comment: class variables{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double number;
        number = 12.34;
        System.out.flush();
        System.out.print(number);
    }
}

Comment: you have asked the same ques twice .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140928/java-eclim-vim-system-out-print-not-working?rq=1

Comment: @Monansh not only that but I gave the answer. Looks like OP didn't read the part when I say that you have to flush "_after_ you print, obviously"...

Comment: @Monansh  "flush AFTER print" not the other way as you wrote...

Comment: sorry.. i have corrected it..

Comment: @Monansh now I changed my downvote to an upvote (the downvote was not meant as an offense but only to mark the answer as wrong as long as it was not corrected)

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certain that it is indeed working, but you are confusing the output with your prompt, as lack of a newline is making the prompt that waits for your next command be in the same line as your printed result.